# HOW TO Generate Equation of a Curve Given (x,y) pairs - algorithm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, approximation-algorithms

Hi,

How can I generate the equation of a curve that matches all arbitrarily given (x,y) pairs? I would like a polynomial of nth degree, where n does not matter, as long as the curve passes thru all the given points.

I guess this problem is NP-complete. If so, how do I find the closest matching curve in a feasible amount of time?

Furthermore; how do I generate a piecewise polynomial, in case the given (x,y) pairs are discontinuous, or they draw the shape of a, say, circle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question will surely get closed, since it's not at research level.  Look up Lagrange interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is an easy and standard procedure (Lagrange Interpolation) that does this. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial